# Handling of resource links in collection of sub-entities with Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring-data-rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I am in the process of evaluating Spring Data REST as a backend for an AngularJS based application. I quickly modeled our domain as a set of aggregate roots and hit the following design roadblock:

- *Model* Resource has
- multiple *Task* Entities
- referencing multiple *Attribute* Resources

I expected the HAL *_links* for the attributes to be placed inside each of the task JSON object, but sadly the attributes are only visible as a link at the root of the JSON construct.

E.g. I get this:

```js
{
  "version": 0,
  "name": "myModel",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "task1"
    },
    {
      "name": "task2"
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/models/1"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/models/1/attributes"
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of something I would image could be like:

```js
{
  "version": 0,
  "name": "myModel",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "task1",
      "_links": {
        "attributes": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/models/1/tasks/1/attributes"
      }
  }
    },
    {
      "name": "task2",
      "_links": {
        "attributes": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/models/1/tasks/2/attributes"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/models/1"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/models/1/attributes"
    }
  }
}
```

Incidentally, in the first example, the *attributes* link ends in a 404.

I haven't seen anything in the HAL spec to handle this kind of cases, nor in the Spring Data REST documentation. Obviously, I could define the task as a resource to workaround the problem, however my model does not require this. I feel like this is a legitimate use case.

I created a simple Spring Boot application that reproduces this issue. The models:

```java
@Entity
public class Model {

    @Id @GeneratedValue public Long id;
    @Version public Long version;

    public String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    public List<Task> tasks;

}

@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id @GeneratedValue public Long id;

    public String name;

    @ManyToMany
    public Set<Attribute> attributes;

}

@Entity
public class Attribute {

    @Id @GeneratedValue public Long id;
    @Version public Long version;

    public String name;
}
```

And repositories:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ModelRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Model, Long> {
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AttributeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Attribute,Long> {
}
```

There, I may have missed something as this seems like quite a simple use case but could not find anyone with a similar problem on SO. Also, maybe this is a fundamental flaw in my model, and if so I'm ready to hear your arguments :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because Spring Data REST does not handle natively the use case described in the question, the first step is to deactivate the management of the Task's Attributes, and ensure they are not serialized by default. Here the `@RestResource(exported=false)` ensures that a (non working) link will not get automatically generated for an "attributes" rel, and the `@JsonIgnore` ensures that attributes will not be rendered by default.

```java
@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    public String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Attribute> attributes;
}
```

Next, the `_links` attribute is only available at the root of our resource, so I chose to implement a new rel named "taskAttributes", that will have multiple values, one for each of the task. To add those links to the resource, I built a custom `ResourceProcessor`, and to implement the actual endpoints, a custom `ModelController`:

```java
@Component
public class ModelResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<Model>> {

    @Override
    public Resource<Model> process(Resource<Model> modelResource) {
        Model model = modelResource.getContent();
        for (int i = 0; i < model.tasks.size(); i++) {
            modelResource.add(linkTo(ModelController.class, model.id)
                    .slash("task")
                    .slash(i)
                    .slash("attributes")
                    .withRel("taskAttributes"));
        }
        return modelResource;
    }
}

@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/models/{id}")
public class ModelController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/task/{index}/attributes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Resources<PersistentEntityResource>> taskAttributes(
            @PathVariable("id") Model model,
            @PathVariable("index") int taskIndex,
            PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {
        if (model == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        if (taskIndex < 0 || taskIndex >= model.tasks.size()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        List<Attribute> attributes = model.tasks.get(taskIndex).attributes;

        List<PersistentEntityResource> resources = attributes.stream()
                .map(t -> assembler.toResource(t))
                .collect(toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new Resources(resources));
    }
}
```

This makes a call to `http://localhost:8080/api/models/1` return something like this:

```
{
  "name": "myModel",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "task1"
    },
    {
      "name": "task2"
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/models/1"
    },
    "model": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/models/1{?projection}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "taskAttributes": [
      {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/models/1/task/0/attributes"
      },
      {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/models/1/task/1/attributes"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Finally, to make all this more usable from the UI, I added a Projection on the Model resource:

```java
@Projection(name = "ui", types = {Model.class, Attribute.class})
public interface ModelUiProjection {
    String getName();
    List<TaskProjection> getTasks();

    public interface TaskProjection {
        String getName();
        List<AttributeUiProjection> getAttributes();
    }
    public interface AttributeUiProjection {
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Which lets one get a subset of the Attribute's properties without the need to fetch them from the "taskAttributes" rel:

`http://localhost:8080/api/models/1?projection=ui` returns something like this:

```
{
  "name": "myModel",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "task1",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "name": "attrForTask1",
          "_links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "http://localhost:8080/attributes/1{?projection}",
              "templated": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "task2",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "name": "attrForTask2",
          "_links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "http://localhost:8080/attributes/2{?projection}",
              "templated": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "anotherAttrForTask2",
          "_links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "http://localhost:8080/attributes/3{?projection}",
              "templated": true
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/models/1"
    },
    "model": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/models/1{?projection}",
      "templated": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a repository for Tasks - in spring data rest you do not have a controller if you do not have a repository. I think you would get a link if a task would just hold one attribute - but you have a Set - so the access to the attributes would be a sub-resource of the task resource.

So your scenario just does not work. I would try to have a TaskRepository that you export and remove the attribute repository.

Then your model resource would contain the link to its task and the task resource would embed the attributes.

You could work with projections if you still wanted to have the tasks inlined into your model resource.

Comment: Hi Mathias, thank you for your answer. Actually my Tasks do not have a Repository by design. They are not resources, and could be seen as value objects. My problem is having two inner objects reference different sets of the same resources, and being able to differentiate the corresponding links.

Comment: I think I got your problem. If you want such a link 'http://localhost:8080/models/1/tasks/2/attributes' tasks needs to be a resource - because attributes would be a sub-resource of task and thus in spring data rest it needs repository. At least if you want no custom controller method. You could try a custom controller method that handles 'models/1/tasks/2/attributes' then you could try to implement a `ResourceProcessor` and add the links to this controller method manually in the ResourceProcessor. Not sure if this would work - but would be worth a try.

Comment: Yes, I reached somewhat the same conclusion as a way to implement what I need, as it does not seem the use case can be handled natively. I will experiment and come back here with my findings, thanks.